# IIS7.5 Permissions

Tags: iis, iis-7

I'm having issues installing Blackboard 8 on IIS7.5.

The installer fails when it tries to add an isapi filter.

Would there be any permissions I need to set up in IIS to allow the installer to add a filter?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just have to run the installer "as administrator...".

Comment: I'm running the installer with an administrator account.

Comment: Running a process with an administrator account isn't the same as "Run as administrator..." a process. Check the UAC concept for this.

Comment: I logged on as an administrator. I then opened the command prompt with 'Run as administrator' and ran the installer. The UAC is set to Never Notify but still no success.